# Create a widget for AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

This effort may not be worth it but here is what I am trying to do.

I want to create a widget using the AppBar so I can change the title and images using a single AppBar. When I click on a certain data tile I want to be able to change the title and image so that it corresponds to the data on the tile.

Here is the code for the widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TopAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String ABTitle;

  const TopAppBar(
      {super.key,
      required this.ABTitle});

@override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      title: Text("$ABTitle"),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code where I am trying to use it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:txntracker/screens/widgets/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:txntracker/screens/widgets/app_bar_top.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home_screen';

 @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

// This is the list of different screens for the Navigation Bar
final List<Widget> appScreens = [
  // const HomeScreen(),
  // const DataParamsScreen(),
  // //RadarMapScreen(),
  // //const MapPropertySearchResults(),
  // const ChatScreen(),
];

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int selectedPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: TopAppBar(title: Text("Home Page")),  <<<< ERROR HERE
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNav(  // Navigation Bar widget
        selectedPage: selectedPage,
        onDestinationSelected: (index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedPage = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where I implement the custom appbar I am getting an error: **The named parameter 'ABTitle' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.**

I am passing the text as a parameter but I am getting the error.
How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: it should be `TopAppBar(ABTitle: "Home Page")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The named parameter `ABTitle` is required, but you're trying to add `title` parameter. Now, you are using your own custom appBar so you can't access Flutter's built-in AppBar property `title`(If you don't make your own property called title).

So, you should call like `TopAppBar(ABTitle: "Home Page")`

**One more tip:** In your custom appbar, you wrote `Text("$ABTitle")`, you can call `Text(ABTitle)` as well.

> DON’T use string interpolation if there’s only a string expression in it.